# SQL SERVER replace function working odd

Tags: sql-server, replace

Why do i get only one Result?

```
    select replace(N'2',N'2','X') as Text
    union 
    select replace(N'2',N'²','X') as Text
```

The second SELECT statement includes a squared.

@@version= Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5623.0

Comment: `N'2'` must be getting treated identically as `N'²'`.

Comment: Are you certain that you really entered a squared into the query?

Comment: Here is the proof `select 1 where N'²'=N'2'` returns `1`. Looks like in SQL SERVER `'²'='2'`.  So both the selects replaced with `X`

Comment: However the `ASCII` value differs. `SELECT ASCII('²'),ASCII('2')` returns `178` and `50` respectively

Comment: Replace as a function is limited in part to your environment. For example, ASCII codes 32 and 255 (space and non-breaking space) are treated exactly the same unless specifically called. Your environment shows a space, but they are not. In the same way,you may find using the actual ASCII code in your function ensures accuracy. Basically, are you sure REPLACE is actually reading it like you think it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior depends on the case-sensitivity of the collation:

```
SELECT REPLACE(N'2' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, N'2'  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'X'  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) as Text
UNION 
SELECT REPLACE(N'2' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, N'²'  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS,'X'  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) as Text
GO
--results:
X
2
SELECT REPLACE(N'2' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, N'2'  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,'X'  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) as Text
UNION 
SELECT REPLACE(N'2' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, N'²'  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,'X'  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) as Text
GO
--results:
X
```

When no collation is specified for literal expressions, the database default collation is used.